# TSQL: group by Substring (Name) and retrieve ID in SELECT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, substring

We have companies' data stored in a table. In an effort to de-duplicate the rows, we need to identify duplicate data sets of companies by using following criterion: If First five letters of the CompanyName, City and postal code match with other records' same fields then it is a duplicate. We will later remove the duplicates. The problem I am running in to is that I can't retrieve  IDs of these records since I am not grouping the records on ID. 
I am using following SQL:

```
Select count(ID) as DupCount
       , SUBSTRING(Name,1,5) as Name
       , City
       , PostalCode 
from tblCompany 
group by SUBSTRING(Name,1,5)
         , City
         , PostalCode 
Having count(ID) > 1 
order by count(ID) desc
```

How do I retrieve the ID of these  records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
Select c.*
from (select c.*,
             count(*) over (partition by left(Name, 5), City, PostalCode) as cnt
      from tblCompany c
     ) c
where cnt >= 2;
```

This will return the individual rows with dups.  You can then summarize this or do what you want with the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`group_concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to get the ids as a comma separated list:

```
select 
  SUBSTRING(Name,1,5) as Name,
  City,
  PostalCode,
  count(ID) as counter, 
  group_concat(id order by id) as ids
from tblCompany 
group by SUBSTRING(Name,1,5), City, PostalCode 
having count(ID) > 1 
order by count(ID) desc
```